# How long does it take to learn to layn Megillas Ester?

Tags: torah-reading, megillat-esther, adult-learning

How much time would it take to learn Megilla layning to the level of a pro with zero prior layning experience?

Comment: Most bar mitzvah students plan about a year to learn their parsha. This would probably be similar?

Comment: @DoubleAA as a bar mitzvah teacher, that is usually far too long for the bar mitzvah boy...

Comment: @רבות ok I guess they're also learning haftara and to be a chazzan. But on the other hand most bar mitzvah boys don't layn at the level of a pro, and Esther is more like a double parsha in length (~10 Torah size columns)

Comment: @DoubleAA very true.  From my very, very minimal experience with Esther for adults, it's somewhat easier, and would likely be learned by memorizing a recording rather than learning the trop and then the actual Megillah.  Should something like this be posted as an answer?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות See my answer below. I don't think it's easier. It's harder, because it's much longer than the average parsha, has really long verses and long tough words found nowhere else in *Tanach*.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92/759

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been a Torah reader for about 45 years, and have read Megilla for about 20 years. This is tough to give you an exact assessment, here, because there are several factors here. So, take what I write as my own "best professional" opinion.

I'm going to assume throughout that you can both read and pronounce Hebrew well. (I've been listening to numerous Bar Mitzvah boys in my shul that can't, but some of them are reading the maftir and haftarah and are butchering everything. So, pardon, my having to state the assumption, but I hope I'm right. If not, then my estimates are going to be **way** off.)

Most Bar Mitzvah boys do spend a year learning their parsha. I agree that it's way too long for most assuming that your diligent. That means that you need to practice your notes and parsha about once per week. An average parsha is about 100 verses. If you practice once per week, I think a competent musically inclined person could do a competent job in about 6-8 months assuming no prior knowledge.

My method, though, is "unconventional". Most Bar Mitzvah teachers start by teaching each individual trope sound and trope "groups" and have students practice and review this for 2 - 3 weeks. It's nice to know the theory, and it can't hurt. But, I have found that many Bar Mitvah boys are nervous / stressed by the Bar Mitzvah itself (much of this is really the parents' fault, BTW) and focusing on this can be more frustrating than it's worth. Even for adults that will lain, occasionally, this can be useful, but it's unnecessary. You can learn the parsha like you're learning a song without even knowing the names of the notes.

The Megilla is a constant. The words never and trope never change from one year to the next. Also, it's the only trope "mode" of its kind. (I.e., Torah trope sounds one way, haftara another way, and its "portable" to multiple parshiot.) So, in short, the learning method for Megilla is the same as for Torah. Learn it like a song (i.e., don't waste your time on what each trope sounds like, unless that interests or helps you.)

Now extrapolate the time estimate above. The Megilla has about 200 verses. Now, I'm not suggesting that it will take you double the time as learning a Torah parsha, but it might. Offhand, I think that if you review a chapter once per week, you should be able to do it in about 8 months.

Some factors that will affect this time:

- Your musical inclination / ear / competency. You don't have to have a stellar voice, but you definitely can't be completely tone deaf either. The better you can memorize the sound, tone, nuances, the quicker it will be.
- How good is your memory for music and word pronunciations? The Megillah has both the longest verses in Tanac"h (that does make it quite challenging) as well as some of the more unusual "tough" pronouncing words in Tanac"h.
- How much time can you review and how frequently? Obviously, the more frequently you practice the quicker things will go. But, you must practice frequently, because it's easy to forget what you did if you don't.
- What's your stamina and determination? You will make many mistakes at the beginning, especially, as well as throughout this venture. If you're the type of person that gets easily frustrated and gives up ... well, my friend, maybe this venture isn't for you.

I strongly encourage you to learn from a competent *Ba'al Kri'a*, but most of all someone who is extremely patient and someone who encourages and believes in your competence. This is a tough project for a beginner to do on his own. There are various tapes / CDs and online resources. But, none of them will either correct you or give you useful criticism, which is really what you will need.

Another method you can use - but you really need a good musical ear. I learned Torah laining mainly by attending shul weekly and following along with the Chumash and listening to my shul's professional *Ba'al Kri'a* (Torah reader.) I focused on a set of trope notes and picked up the sound and rhythm by listening to the reading. In my case, by the time I was taking Bar Mitzvah lessons with the *Ba'al Kri'a* and my parents and neighbors said I needed about 8 months, the *Ba'al Kri'ah* heard me and said I needed about 3 months. Alas, few shuls now use a hired reader who is the same one each week, so this may pose a challengs. But, if you have a good musical ear, you can do it this way.

*Megilla* won't be as quick because it's read just twice per year. But, you could, technically, learn it from a tape / CD if you have a sharp musical ear. It's not for everyone, obviously.

I hope all this info helps. Best of luck.

Comment: This is the best type of answer to a question like this.  +1

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Why , thank you, sir.  It comes from much experience. Laining has been my "job" for a long time, and not only do I still enjoy it, but I am always trying to find ways to sharpen my skills. When I lain, I compare it to performing a piano concerto in front of large audience in Carnegie Hall. Mind you, my shul sometimes barely gets a minyan, but my point is that the audience expects perfection, and I expect to give a perfect performance. It really is that important. If only every *Ba'al Kri'ah* had this attitude. I think too many rush through it or are "winging" it.

Comment: +1 but "I think that's a waste for someone that will not become a professional weekly reader" - that's a little pessimistic to me.  Even if they don't end up having to do it every week, you never know when you'll be called on to learn an aliyah or 2.  Also, it's super important to know at least some of the theory so that you know which pauses are bigger than others.

Comment: @Heshy You make a good point. I should probably rephrase that point. I said that based on the majority of Bar Mitzvah boys that I have seen and after speaking to a few "trainers". (I do little training, myself. I have to admit that I'm probably too demanding for most Bar Mitzvah students, and I can't deal with petty complainers.) Most boys just do their parsha and it's an effort for them. Few will lain afterwards. But, even for those that do, occasionally, for one or two aliyot, they can learn from a tape or get a tutor.

Comment: @Heshy Proof of my point, perhaps - In my shul, the haftara is assigned to different people sometimes months in advance. (Interesting phenomenon in many Conservative shuls that haftarah is a HUGE deal.) Most of the adults (In their 50's - 70's) don't know a thing about trope sounds. They ask the chazzan, rabbi or the Bar Mitzvah teacher to train them or they have a CD somewhere. And some are called a few times per year.

Comment: I'd say that's a proof of MY point - if they learned it properly once, they could lein any haftara or even any pasuk in Navi with zero preparation!  (I'm exaggerating a little, there are some weird things like the mercha kefula in the haftara of Behaaloscha/Chanuka and the pronunciation of וקוי in the haftara of Lech Lecha, and once you go outside of the haftaros you get things like shalshelet where AFAIK there's no Ashkenazi mesorah so you have to make up something reasonable, but you get the idea.)  Unless your shul uses a Navi scroll?  But it doesn't sound like it from your description.

Comment: @Heshy I don't think there's any argument. I agree that it certainly would be more efficient. I'm just saying that it's not necessary. For my shul haftara readers - they prob. don't have the time or patience to bother with the theory. So, all I'm saying is that they can successfully lain the haftara, anyway, by "song memorizing". And, no - we don't use a scroll. The last place I saw that was in a *Yekke* shul in Brooklyn about 20 years ago. I think that shul is now a church :-( But, maybe they're doing their own "haftarah".